# Created a menu in Android but the menu is not visible

Tags: java, android

I have created a menu in my android-app, but the menu is not visible when I test my app on my phone. Why is this?

Here is my menu.xml:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item  android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item 1"/>
    <item  android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item 2"/>
    <item  android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:title="Item 3"/>

</menu>
```

And here is my onOptionItemSelected method in my MainActivity:

```
protected boolean onOptionItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 1 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 2 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item3:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 3 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

My onCreateOptionMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

What have I missed?

Edit. I added the onCreateOptionMenu which I forgot. The menu is now visible, but the onOptionItemSelected method is not working. Nothing is happening when I choose any of the options.

Full activity here:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private ImageView compassImage;

    private float initialDegree = 0f;
    private float currentDegree;
    private SensorManager manager;

    TextView infoTextAboutDegrees;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makeCall);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                emergencyCall();
            }
        });


        compassImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCompass);

        infoTextAboutDegrees = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeading);

        manager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        manager.registerListener(this, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        manager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    public void emergencyCall() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:911"));

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            Log.i("Call success...", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Call fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


        currentDegree = Math.round(event.values[0]);

        infoTextAboutDegrees.setText("Current degrees: " + Float.toString(currentDegree));

        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(
                initialDegree,
                -currentDegree,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f);

        rotateAnimation.setDuration(210);

        rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        compassImage.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
        initialDegree = -currentDegree;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {


    }

    protected boolean onOptionItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 1 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.item2:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 2 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.item3:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 3 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use appcompat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo - always add the @Override then you see it on your own:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Jesus, how on earth did I miss that. Feeling so stupid now, lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Override onCreateOptionsMenu() and inflate the menu in that method.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
return true;
}
```

Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, You integrated below code to create option menu.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
```

if you are using fragments then please use this:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

I hope it will work.

remove code from your menu xml:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it now and let you know how it went.

Comment: Welcome @SandeepSing, please use your menu xml at the place of  R.menu.activity_main.

Comment: Tried it. Still no menu.

Comment: do you use appcompat?

Comment: No, I dont. Don't even know what it is. @ligi

Comment: @SandeepSing You might still use it even if you do not know it - can you show your full activity? Then we see ..

Comment: Ok. Yogendra, I cant remove that code from my xml. I get a bunch of errors if I do.

Comment: @ligi Just updated my post, please see my full acitivty

Comment: @SandeepSing that looks good - you do not use appcompat - do you have a phone with a physical menu key by any chance? If so just press it - and there is a trick to show the items anyway ..

Comment: @SandeepSing - yes this cannot work - see my answer why

Answer (score 0):

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {...}

not protected.